# Lighttpd Skip auth for ip

Tags: ip, authentication, lighttpd

I have setup a login for a domain with lighttpd 1.4.31, no problem.

Now, I would like to skip this login for a single IP address.

I have tried a few different configs I found in the [documentation](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration) and [online](http://charles.lescampeurs.org/lighttpd-password-protection) but somehow it is not working:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(private.mypage.net)$" {
    #$HTTP["remoteip"] !~ "^(81\.209\.1\.1|87\.128\.1\.1)$" {
    #$HTTP["remoteip"] != "87.128.1.1" {
    $HTTP["remoteip"] !~ "^(87\.128\.1\.)" {
        auth.require = (
            "/" =>
            (
                "method"  => "basic",
                "realm"   => "Private",
                "require" => "valid-user"
            )
        )
    }
}
```

I triple checked the IP but I always get the login.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out first try was correct `$HTTP["remoteip"] !~ "^(81\.209\.1\.1|87\.128\.1\.1)$" {`.

Problem was a second auth.require for the same folder. Did not see that because it was defined in another domain and should not have been applied here.